# MYSQL Show one row only in same ID based on Timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp, selection

How can I select **one row only** in same ID?

**This is my MySQL Code**

```
Select * from logoutdetails ORDER BY LogInTime DESC LIMIT 1;
```

**This is my Table**

```
--------------------------------
|  ID  |  LogInTime            |
--------------------------------
|  07  |  2017-01-25 14:41:32  |
|  08  |  2017-01-25 14:33:22  |
|  07  |  2017-01-25 14:26:28  |
|  08  |  2017-01-25 14:18:56  |
--------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by the `id` to get only unique ones. Then you have to decide which date you want to get for each `id`. Use `max()` to get the latest date for each

```
Select id, max(LogInTime) as LogInTime
from logoutdetails 
group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are satisfied with taking the most recent timestamp from each `ID` then you can try this:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(LogInTime) AS LogInTime
FROM logoutdetails
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
```

You could also use `MIN()` in place of `MAX()`, if you wanted to retain the earliest login time.

If the `logoutdetails` table had other columns and you wanted to select those too, you would have to use a subquery to first identify the maximum `ID` records and then join back to your original table.  Something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM logoutdetails t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, MAX(LogInTime) AS max_login_time
    FROM logoutdetails
    GROUP BY ID
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND
       t1.LogInTime = t2.max_login_time
```